# If $R_P$ is reduced, is there a Zariski basic open set $D(f)$ containing $P$ such that $R_f$ is also reduced?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, localization, affine-schemes, zariski-topology

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity.

If $P\in \operatorname{Spec} R\:$ is such that $R_P$ is reduced, then is it necessarily true that $\exists f\in R\setminus P$, i.e., $f\in R$ such that $P\in D(f)$, such that $R_f$ is also reduced ? If this is not true in general, what if we assume $R$ is Noetherian ?

(Here by reduced ring we mean a ring with no non-zero nilpotent element.)

Comment: You need to assume at least Noetherianity : take $R=\mathbb Z[x_i, y_i, i\in \mathbb N]/(x_i^2, x_iy_i)$ and $P=(x_i, i\in \mathbb N)$. Then inverting the $y_i$'s has the effect of killing off the $x_i$'s so $R_P$ is reduced, but if you only invert one element, then you invert at most finitely many $y_i$'s and the $x_k$ ($y_k$ not inverted) aren't dead but still nilpotent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I explained in the comments why Noetherianity is necessary (I can replicate the argument here if you want), here's why it's enough :

if $R$ is Noetherian, then its nilradical $\mathrm{Nil}(R)$ is finitely generated, say by $x_1,...,x_n$. $R_P$ is reduced, meaning $x_1,...,x_n$ are $0$ in $R_P$, so in particular there are $s_1,...,s_n\notin P$ such that $s_ix_i=0$.

If you now invert $f=s_1...s_n$ (which obviously isn't in $P$) then of course you invert each $s_i$ and so $x_i = 0$ in $R_f$.

Moreover, if $e^k = 0$ in $R_f$, then for some $l$ we have $f^le^k=0$ in $R$. Therefore (multiply by enough $f$ or enough $e$) you get for some $r$, $(fe)^r=0$ in $R$.It follows that $fe=\sum_i \lambda_i x_i$ in $R$, thus if you invert $f$, since the $x_i$ die, you get $e=0$ in $R_f$: $R_f$ is reduced.

Comment: from $f^le^k=0$ in $R$, how did you get $e^k=0$ in $R$ ?

Comment: from $f^le^k=0$ in $R$, I can deduce $e^k=0$ in $R_P$ , so $e=0$ in $R_P$ since $R_P$ is reduced , so $se=0$ in $R$ for some $s\in R\setminus P$ ...  but I can't see why $e^k=0$ in $R$ ... would you please clarify ?

Comment: Sorry I spoke too quickly, I think I can change my argument and make it work however, see the edited answer

Comment: Sorry about that, it should be correct now hopefully

Comment: $N(R_f)=N(R)_f=0$ since one knows that all generators of the nilradical are zero in $R_f$.

Comment: @Max I find it confusing that you say "Noetherianity is necessary." Didn't you show that any ring with f.g. nilradical has the property?

Comment: @BadamBaplan : you are of course right that Noetherianity is not necessary in the sense that the property does not imply noetherianity; what I meant was that some finiteness hypothesis was necessary, and the standard one is "noetherian" + I was referring to the OP who asked "If this is not true in general, what if we assume R is Noetherian ?". But you are right, it is an imprecise phrasing (and if taken literally, it is false)